# How can i download specified file from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download one file from my s3 bucket

I'm trying this command:

```
aws s3 sync %inputS3path% %inputDatapath% --include "20211201-1500-euirluclprd01-olX8yf.1.gz"
```

and I habve also tried_

```
aws s3 sync %inputS3path% %inputDatapath% --include "*20211201-1500-euirluclprd01-olX8yf.1*.gz"
```

but when command is executing, I'm get all file that's include folder

Folder looks like :

```
/2021/12/05
20211201-1500-euirluclprd01-olX8yf.1.gz
20211201-1505-euirluclprd01-olX8yf.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aws s3 cp` to copy a specific file. For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/path/file.gz .
```

Looking at your variables, you could probably use:

```
aws s3 cp %inputS3path%/20211201-1500-euirluclprd01-olX8yf.1.gz %inputDatapath%
```